# how to customise the bootstrap select dropdown with border radius and appearance change in angular13 without using any plugin

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Hi i am using bootstrap select dropdown, but i want to make its appearance look like the below image, but no plugin's to be installed. i tried in these ways but didnt work. this new dropdown design must have same functionality as normal select dropdown does, like from binding dropdpown values to the select field and giving value of the selected dropdown.

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-dropdown-x72ugp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-3 mb-3">
                <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Project</label>
                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" >
                    <option selected value="">Select Project</option>
                    <option value="ACTIVE">Active</option>
                    <option value="Terminate">TERMINATED</option>
                  </select>
                 </div>
```

CSS:

```
select.form-select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  background: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 24 24'><path fill='grey' d='M7.406 7.828l4.594 4.594 4.594-4.594 1.406 1.406-6 6-6-6z'></path></svg>") #fff;
  background-position: 98% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Need design like this:

[image: sample UI]

Comment: Isn't that a dropdown, and not a select? Or am I wrong?

Comment: code what i have written is select dropdown using bootstrap but i need to customise that design like the image, bcz that is the design given and plugin must not be used

Comment: The image that you are trying to achieve, I am pretty sure it is some sort of example from Bootstrap Dropdowns

Comment: in Angular bootstrap it is there, but it doesnt work as this normal bootstrap dropdown, i want the choosen dropdown value to be binded and must given me value as well

Comment: any help , please?

Comment: I believe you can't really change so specifically the box that `select` has. Your best try would actually try and use Dropdowns from Bootstrap, and make them return a value, when selected

Comment: ya ok i will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go...

#### Solution 1:

`ngx-bootstrap`

See the StackBlitz snippet [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-bootstrap4-dropdown-73u1go?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

---

**UPDATE**

#### Solution 2:

`ng-bootstrap`

See the StackBlitz snippet [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular12-bootstrap-junsgu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css).

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  clickMessage = 'Choose an option';

  getText(text) {
    this.clickMessage = text;
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<body class="p-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
        <button
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          id="dropdownBasic1"
          ngbDropdownToggle
        >
          {{ clickMessage }}
        </button>
        <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
          <button
            ngbDropdownItem
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
          >
            Option 1
          </button>
          <button
            ngbDropdownItem
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
          >
            Option 2
          </button>
          <button
            ngbDropdownItem
            class="nav-link"
            href="#"
            (click)="getText($event.target.innerText)"
          >
            Option 3
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**app.component.css**

```
.btn {
  width: 200px;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

button:focus,
button:active {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 5px #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.nav-link {
  color: black;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  color: black;
  border: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, is it possible to make that value get binded to that button, i mean same as select dropdown?

Comment: You mean that when you click, let's say "Option 1" that the value is displayed inside the `<button>`?

Comment: yes exactly, and by default one of the option must be selected, it is like i must get the event what i have selected and that option must be binded

Comment: oh sorry this is done using ngx-bootstrap right?

Comment: ngb-bootstrap is allowed and bootstrap 5 is allowed here

Comment: I updated my answer. What about now?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the same way i need using angular bootstrap, but you have used ngx-bootstrap which is not approved for me

Comment: I just forked your StackBlitz snippet. You didn't stated that you don't want to use `ngx-bootstrap`. Which "Angular Bootstrap" are you talking about? Can you give me some links to the official website please?

Comment: yes but at the top, i mentioned no plugin's to be installed, but i can upvote your answer and accept, that will help some other people who are in need, but i need this in ngbootstrap or Angular bootstrap or normal bootstrap 5

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245258/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-cervus-camelopardalis).

Comment: Any help?? Any hint

Comment: Sorry, I'm very busy and don't have enough time to find a solution. This might help you: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples. Also, here's a live demo: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fmain.ts.

Comment: sorry demo link is not opening, can you please give me link again

Comment: My bad. Here you go: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/stackblitzes/dropdown/basic/stackblitz.html

Comment: this is example of bootstrap, are you giving me that link ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72507745/how-to-detect-value-is-present-under-any-of-the-array-inputs-using-angular any help to this question?

Comment: This is an example of `ng-bootstrap` (Angular) not vanilla Bootstrap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245358/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-cervus-camelopardalis).

Comment: I updated my answer (a solution using `ng-bootstrap`).

Comment: thanks a lot, i will check with my application and accept

Comment: is it possible to keep the selected text to start from left instead of starting from middle?

Comment: I updated my answer (see UPDATE 2).

Comment: thanks for the answer, i will accept and vote